# Invalid output formatter when installing a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc

I built a gem for my own usage and when I want to install it I get the following:

```
$ gem install mygem

Successfully installed mygem-0.0.1
1 gem installed
Installing RDoc documentation for mygem-0.0.1...

Invalid output formatter

For help on options, try 'rdoc --help'
```

The gem **works fine**, but I would like to know what is causing this since I never saw it when installing any other gem. Looks like it is somehow related to RDoc but I couldn't find anything searching about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your RDoc output format? A similar question was found here

https://github.com/tenderlove/paddle/issues/1